# Compress billions of files in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, brotli, zstd

We have lots of files in S3 (>1B), I'd like to compress those to reduce storage costs.
What would be a simple and efficient way to do this?

Thank you

Alex

Comment: S3 Batch is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Is your aim simply to reduce costs? Are you familiar with [Object Storage Classes – Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/)? You can reduce the cost of storage, but it is a trade-off with durability and access speed. For example, the Glacier Deep Archive storage class can reduce storage costs by 95%, but data is not immediately accessible. This would be a LOT simpler than compressing files. Can you tell us more about how these files are used?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, storage costs is the main driver here. But I need to keep data accessible.

Comment: @Dunedan You mean use S3 batch with custom Lamda, that will compress the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 cannot compress your data.

You would need to write a program to **run on an Amazon EC2 instance** that would:

- Download the objects
- Compress them
- Upload the files back to S3

An alternative is to use Storage Classes:

- If the data is infrequently accessed, use **S3 Standard - Infrequent Access** -- this is available immediately and is cheaper as long as data is accessed less than once per month
- **Glacier** is substantially cheaper but takes some time to restore (speed of restore is related to cost)